# .asoundrc ALSA configuration for webcam

Tags: linux, audio, configuration, webcam, alsa

I'm an ALSA beginner in the process of setting up my .asoundrc to record audio from my webcam.

Here is what I did to determine that my hardware is actually working:

I'm able to output sound using the following basic .asoundrc

```
defaults.pcm.!card Generic
defaults.pcm.!device 0
defaults.pcm.!ctl Generic
```

And I successfully recorded a test from my webcam with the following command

```
arecord --device=hw:0,0 --duration=5 --format=S16_LE /tmp/test.wav
```

Then, using a rudimentary knowledge of ALSA configuration, I wrote the following .asoundrc

```
pcm.!default {
    type asym
    playback.pcm {
        type hw
        card Generic
        device 0
    }

    capture.pcm {
        type hw
        card 0
        device 0
    }
}
```

However, this results in no sound output or recording functionality. Please help me understand why this is not working.

[output of aplay -l](http://ix.io/2b3I)

[output of arecord -l](http://ix.io/2b3J)

Comment: Why do you think you need an `.asoundrc`? What is the actual problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: With the default alsa setting without a .asoundrc, my computer outputs/records no sound whatsoever.

Comment: Did you tell PulseAudio to use the correct device (`pavucontrol`)?

Comment: Pulseaudio is irrelevant to this discussion.

Comment: What exactly happens when you try to use `aplay` or `arecord` with your new device?